# How to normalize data which has started at different time periods?

Tags: inference, descriptive-statistics, normalization

So I have to review our business producers and have a long list of ones which have been signed up since 2017 with the company. We have continually hired more producers throughout the past three years. How can I  normalize the data to make a true comparison? A small sample of data would like something like this:

Producer 1: Signed Date: 2017/2/10 Produced Units: 134
Producer 2: Signed Date: 2017/5/5 Produced Units: 352
.
.
.
.
Producer N: Signed Date: 2020/01/18 Produced Unites: 42